# Loader widget displays ajax-loader.gif with non-transarent background

Tags: jquery-mobile

[image: loader non-transparent]

The loader in my application looks like above with an unwanted background surrounding it. I cannot get rid of the background, same situation when I use a different transparent ajax-loading.gif. In the same browser the loader looks fine in the demo application:

[image: loader OK]

I am using a theme roller theme but I did not find a setting there which seems to influence the loader plus the css for the loader looks identical in my app and the demo app.

Any clues what could cause the Looks of my loader?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by setting a theme that I am not actually using:

```
$.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "f";
```

My theme seems to have messed the looks of the loader maybe because I am not using rounded corners, but by adding 1em corners (as in the default theme) I could not completely get rid of the glitch.